# MATLAB: Run multiple cases in switch

Tags: matlab

Is there a method for running multiple `case` statements (say 2 out of 3) in a MATLAB `switch`? Or do I have to use a series of `if` statements? I would like do something similar to:

```
test = {'test1','test2'}
switch test
    case 'test1'
        disp('test1')
    case 'test2'
        disp('test2')
    case 'test3'
        disp('test3')
end
```

Output:

```
test1
test2
```

On a side note: is there any way to parallelize such code so that the different cases can be run simultaneously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `if` statement would be more appropriate if you 1/ want to test for multiple cases 2/parallelize.

something like

```
if ismember('test1',test)
     %code
end
```

if you want to make it parallel, you can do it through the following:

`test` is your data, `case` is the cell containing all possiblities

```
parfor(i=1:length(cases)){ %you need to parse the cases not the data
      if(ismember(case{i},test)){
       %code
      }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution can be put the `switch` into a function and then use the `cellfun`. Hence, define the function:

```
function a = func(test)
    switch test
        case 'test1'
            disp('test1')
        case 'test2'
            disp('test2')
        case 'test3'
            disp('test3')
    end
end
```

then, apply to the `test`:

```
cellfun(@func, test)
```

The result would be:

```
test1 
test2
```